# Pushing file to server more efficiently

Tags: rsync

I have a cluster of daemon running on Mac that generate a lot of jpg in a folder like this `content/categoryname`. The category name is considered as unique across multiple machine. So what is the easiest way to push all these file from multiple machine to the central server.

Currently I using mv command to do it and basically it overwriting existing file but since there is a huge chance the file already exist it waste a lot of time and IO in doing things unnecessarily.

The reason for doing these is the Mac machine have limited storage and I need them cleared constantly so they can continue generating more. 
I am thinking of using rsync but not sure if that is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Try **rsync**

```
rsync -u <src> <dest>
```

it will copy filest but if file exists it will skip files that are newer on the destination